# translated inline does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, translate

Can't use inline translation tool on my webpage. Its working fine in backed. I checked on the frontent if Translate Inline>"Enabled for Fronted"` is enabled, but it wasn't. when I translating something it does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Mozila, crome have some problem.

After edit it , please flush cache and check it.